# How to reset counter in a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void drop(){
    //6 * 7 = 42 turns, 6 * 9 = 54 turns
    int totalTurns = 0;
    int tempRow = 5;
    int counter = 0;
    while(totalTurns <= 5){
        System.out.println("What column would you like to drop a piece into?: ");
        Scanner scannerBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int columnInput = scannerBoard.nextInt();
        if(columnInput <= boardArray[0].length){
            if(boardArray[5][columnInput] == ' '){
                boardArray[5][columnInput] = 'x';

            }
            else if(boardArray[5][columnInput] == 'x'){
                if(boardArray[5-counter][columnInput] == ' '){
                    boardArray[5- counter][columnInput] = 'x';

                }
                counter += 1;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }

            totalTurns = totalTurns + 1;
            if(counter== boardArray.length){
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

Do you want to play Normal or Expert mode: 
normal
[[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]]
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
0
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
0
1
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
0
2
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
0
3
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
1
What column would you like to drop a piece into?: 
1
4
[[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [ , x,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [x,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [x,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [x, x,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm trying to place a 'x' on top of each other. I noticed that if I enter the same column it works fine. But as soon as I enter a different column, the decrement variable does not reset back to zero. How would I go about resetting the variable back to zero as I continue to a different column?

Comment: Keep track of the previous column number: `if (currentColumn != previousColumn) { counter = 0; }`.

Comment: If my input variable is columnInput, should I make the currentColumn = columnInput then? What would I make the previousColumn variable?

Comment: `if (columnInput != previousColumn) { counter = 0; }` but you will also want to count how many x's are in that supplied columnInput already. `for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.length; i++) { if (boardArray[i][columnInput] == 'x') {counter++; } }`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish what I think you are trying to do. If you want to keep using your own code then try what I suggested in comments, It's not to difficult to implement.

If you want to try something a little different however then the concept below might be somewhat better for you. The code merely takes the User supplied column number and inspects that column within the Game Board matrix for **X**'s and increments the `counter` variable for every **X** found in the column throughout the entire matrix. It then determines which matrix row is empty to accept yet another **X** for that column. Every `while` loop iteration resets the counter to 1 then that counter is incremented dependent upon the number of **X**'s detected within the supplied column.

The code is a runnable and contains several comments which you should read. Since I have no clue how this game is played you will need code in the limits and rules for the game:

```
public class OrthelloMatrixDemo {

    private char[][] boardArray;
    private final java.util.Scanner scannerBoard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    private final int boardRows = 6;
    private final int boardColumns = 7;
    
    // Example turns calculation: 
    // 6 rows x 7 columns = 42 turns OR
    // 6 rows x 9 columns = 54 turns
    private final int turns = boardRows * boardColumns;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Done to avoid the need for statics
        new OrthelloMatrixDemo().startGame(args);
    }
    
    private void startGame(String[] args) {
        // Create the board...
        boardArray = new char[boardRows][boardColumns];
        for (int i = 0; i < boardRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardColumns; j++) {
                boardArray[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        // =============================================
        
        printBoard();  // Print the game Board to console window.
        
        //for (int i = 0; i < (turns); i++) {
            dropGamePiece();
        //}
    }
    
    private void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(boardArray[i]));
        }
    }
    
    public void dropGamePiece() {
        int totalTurns = 0;
        int counter = 1;
        int availRow = boardRows - 1;
        while (totalTurns <= 5) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("What literal column would you like\n"
                           + "to drop a game piece into (1 to " + 
                             boardColumns + ")? --> ");
            int columnInput = -1;
            try {
                // Subtract 1 from the supplied User input value so to
                // hold the index value instead of the literal value.
                columnInput = scannerBoard.nextInt() - 1; 
            }
            catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("You must supply a Column Number "
                               + "from 1 to " + boardColumns + "!");
                // Consume the ENTER key hit otherwise this Exception 
                // will just keep printing to console indefinately. 
                scannerBoard.nextLine(); 
                continue;  // Go to top of loop
            }
            
            // Make sure a value from 1 to 7 is supplied.
            if ((columnInput + 1) < 1 || (columnInput + 1) > boardColumns) {
                System.out.println("You can not supply a column number\n"
                               + "less than 1 or greater than " + boardColumns + "!");
                continue;  // Go to top of loop
            }
            counter = 1;    // Start counter from 1
            // Count how many X's are already in supplied column.
            for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.length; i++) { 
                if (boardArray[i][columnInput] == 'x') {
                    counter++; 
                } 
            }
            // Determine the next available row to drop a 
            // game piece into the supplied column.
            availRow = boardRows - counter;
            if (availRow < 0) {
                System.out.println("Column " + (columnInput + 1) + " is aready full!");
                continue;  // Go to top of loop
            }
            boardArray[availRow][columnInput] = 'x';
            System.out.println("Column " + (columnInput + 1) +
                            " contains " + counter + " X's." );
            printBoard(); // Print the game Board to console window.
            totalTurns++;
        }
    }
}
```